My XAML has lost all compatibility, libraries. Rebuilding does not fix
I have two main libraries or dependencies in my XAML. These are FluentWPF, translation based on the ".resx" file and Styles created in XAML.
So the XAML gives the following errors:
"Error XDG0005 Could not load file or assembly 'FluentWPF, Version=0.10.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The file specified cannot be found."* and
"Error XDG0024 Could not load file or assembly 'OnGaki, Version=0.0.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The file specified cannot be found.*"
These errors are translated into English.*
My code is big in XAML and I will leave some of the code.

How I create these compatibility (I don't know exactly what it's called, sorry)

xmlns:fw="clr-namespace:SourceChord.FluentWPF;assembly=FluentWPF"

xmlns:language="clr-namespace:OnGaki.LanguagesRes"


A piece of code where errors of one compatibility and the second are displayed.

<Border x:Name="BorderRight" Background="{fw:AcrylicBrush TintColor=Black, TintOpacity=0.4, NoiseOpacity=0}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Margin="5" CornerRadius="0 10 10 0"/>

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static language:Lang.LastAlbum_ScrollInfo}" Margin="10 0 0 0" FontSize="14" Foreground="DarkGray"/>

<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonCheckedDown}" Height="25" Width="50" Margin="2 0 2 0" Click="LyricHidePannell_Click"/>

Now my XAML looks like this:enter image description here
When launched, the program should look like this (The fact that the main part (Main page) disappears is normal.):enter image description here
Perhaps one screenshot won't do, but I hope for at least an idea of ​​how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.
I tried to rebuild the project, clear the NuGet cache, clear the assemblies and rebuild - nothing helps.
My program starts without problems, but it is impossible to work like this.
